# loading nested templates in js dynamically (no data passed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I am working on an offline prototype (html, css and js), and I need a simple mechanism in which i can separate my markup into several external template files for better maintenance and to make it reusable..

mainly these external templates will not have any type of data templating, it will contain only static html,

I need to write a script, which will parse all `data-template-url` attributes, and load the corresponding template file into that DOM element, and if the loaded template has a `data-template-url`, the script will also do the same (no matter how much nested templates there are in my markup)

```
<div class="some-component" data-template-url="components/user-details.html">
    <!-- template content will be loaded here -->
</div>
```

I have done the following script which will do the job, **but does not handle nested templates**

```
(function($){

    $(function(){

        var attr = 'data-template-url';

        $('[' + attr + ']').each(function(){
            var $self = $(this)
            ,   url = $self.attr(attr);

            $.get(url, function(data){
                $(data).appendTo($self);
            });
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

appreciate if anyone can help :)

Comment: Does "offline prototype" imply that you are using `file:///` urls, i.e. do not use a webserver?

Comment: either `file:///` urls or relative one `../file/some.html`, and yes @ThiefMaster , there should be no web server in my solution

Comment: AJAX does not work well on `file:///` URLs in various browsers.

The reason for this is that there is no good way to enforce the same-origin-policy locally. For example, if you save some website locally, you do not want it to have access to all your personal data via XHR.

Comment: aha then i got your first question wrong, as you can see in the example above, i am only using relative urls `controls/user-details.html`

Comment: Why not look into a serverside template-system like Smarty? Smarty is built for this, javascript is...ehm, not the best suited language for such a task.

Comment: @OptimusCrime i am open to third party js libraries, can you provide a working example ?

Comment: @OptimusCrime the solution has to remain only client side, no server sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your approach:

```
(function($){

    $(function(){

        var loadTemplates = function () {

            var 
                /* template url attribute */
                attr = 'data-template-url',
                /* load status attribute */
                state = 'data-template-state',
                /* load done value for status attribute */
                done = 'ready';

            /* for all elements with template url not in ready state */
            $('[' + attr + ']:not([' + state + '="' + done + '"])')
            .each(function () {

                /* fetch url */
                var url = $(this).attr(attr);

                /* load content and append */
                $(this).load(url, function () {

                    /* set state to ready */
                    $(this).attr(state, done);

                    /* do another run for nested templates */
                    loadTemplates();

                });

            });
        };

        /* start */
        loadTemplates();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this will solve only one nested level, also the browser hangs when i added your code, looks like you have an infinite loop.

Comment: The code works on nesting teplates of any level. I don't get a inifinite loop in my tests, so there seem to be a difference in our testing invironments. If two templates include each other, yes, you end with recursive includes and therefore a infinite loop.